# PDO rollback returning FALSE

Tags: sql-server, pdo

In what cases the PDO rollBack() returns false?
I'm experiencing a problem with a complex script working with a MS SQL 2008 R2 database, sometimes the rollBack() returns false but I'm not able to start a new transaction because I'll get a

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is already an active transaction'
```

But if I try to issue another rollBack() call, I get a

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'There is no active transaction'
```

I'm confused.

Comment: Are you using a try/catch block (maybe paste some code)?

Comment: No. The problem does not arise immediately, only after many iterations, so it is difficult to isolate a snippet of code. Btw I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved using closeCursor() after every select statement used in transaction.

The problem didn't arise immediately, only after many transactions (3000+). Maybe some sort of memory leak, btw solved now.

Comment: This is an interesting issue. I would be interested in researching details regarding this as it sounds like an issue that would be sort of hard to debug.